# file upload using OFTP2 protocol in C#

Tags: c#, edi

I want to upload the xml file over the server having OFTP2 protocol in C#. I have done file uploading over normal FTP bot OFTP2 is completely new for me. Please let me know how I can do the same using C#.

Comment: Here is good article : https://www.odette.org/repository/OFTP2_Explained.pdf.  It uses TLS authentication which can be done in Net.

Comment: @jdweng my friend I need some demo example so I implement the same in C#, thanks for your comment dear.